# Gwt Editor framework for interfaces

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

I am trying to implement gwt editor framework.

I have created a driver as follows:

```
final Driver driver = GWT.create(Driver.class);
```

ABC is my class and I am passing object of my ABC class to

```
driver.edit();
```

function.

Now instead of class I want to use Interface.
But since we cant create instance of an interface how shall i proceed 
for the same?
Can we use interfaces in above mentioned case ?

Answer (score 2):

The Editor framework won't ever instantiate anything (other than its own internal things, of course), so using interfaces is safe, and just like with classes.

Try it, it just works.

Comment: An instance of any object implementing the interface. What are you trying to do with interfaces? Anyway, that's nothing to do with editors, just Java/programming skills.